# How to store Graph in a text file using Graphstream

Tags: java, graph, graphstream

I know how to handle graphs using matrices and linked list. I am new to **Graphstream**.  I want to know is there any in-built function in **Graphstream** in java to store/Read **Graph** type graphs in text files and what is the format of storing such graphs in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Reading files using* `FileSource`](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Reading-files-using-FileSource/) lists the file formats supported by concrete implementations of [`FileSource`](https://data.graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/current/org/graphstream/stream/file/FileSource.html). It outlines the use of `readAll()`, as well as reading *event-by-event* from certain formats.

- DGS (GraphStream)
- DOT (GraphViz)
- GML
- TLP (Tulip)
- NET (Pajek)
- GraphML
- GEXF (Gephi)

In particular, [*The DGS File Format Specification*](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Advanced-Concepts/The-DGS-File-Format/) describes DGS, the default GraphStream text file format. In outline, a `FileSource` connects a file to a graph:

```
Graph g = …;
FileSource fs = …;
fs.addSink(g);
fs.readAll(…);
```

> Can I get some sample DGS file online storing big `Graph`?

Some small examples are shown [here](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Advanced-Concepts/The-DGS-File-Format/); a large example of the road network of Le Havre, France is cited [here](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/).

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me. I wonder can i get some sample DGS file online storing big Graph?

Comment: We have a couple of graphs here for testing https://data.graphstream-project.org/pub/dataset/

Comment: More above on the Le Havre data cited by @zer0chain.